# GTM for Mobile Apps doesn't allow to drop parameters longer than 24 characters

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

**Goal**

- Drop parameters names (= key names) that are longer than 24 characters.

**GTM UI**

- When I want to save tag with such a settings, it shows the error message in the area where parameters can be dropped. Please see screenshot here:
  [image]

**Further investigation**

- Problem is in GTM account for Android and iOS as well
- Max length of event-parameter name for GA4 collection is [40 characters](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en)

**Questions**
What is reason for such a behaviour within GTM account? It seems to be an issue, probably bug issue. Is it possible to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug when you specify more than 24 characters of parameter name in the Parameters to Drop section only

Workaround:

- Create a constant variable in GTM
- Input the parameter name in that variable
- Use the constant variable in the Parameters to Drop section instead of string text and it will work

Comment: Thanks for hacky workaround. It works surprisingly.